# File found on run but not after being built

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Working on a little game project, we uses sprites and sound. He're the thing, when we run the project, everything works fine, but when we build the artifact, only the sprites are loaded and we get a FileNotFoundException when trying to load sound.

We uses Intellij, and a little library we found for sound : [jlPLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/package-summary.html)

Here is the little class we use to play sound:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class Son extends Thread{
    private String file;
    public Son(String _file){
        file = _file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ClassLoader c = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(c.getResource(file).getFile());
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            Player player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();

        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the value you pass for the file is correct, then your code looks ok (non canonical, but ok).  It could be that your build is not including the sound files in your archive. Untar the jar file (or war) and see if the sound files are actually present at the path you pass into this code.

Comment: Yes there are also in the Jar. And the thing is that we retrieves the sprites the exact same way.

Comment: The "file" might not actually be a file, but an entry in a jar. Use `getResourceAsStream` instead of trying to create a FileInputStream.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it finally works but I do not get why ?

Comment: Try printing out what c.getResource(file) returns. And what .getFile() returns.

Comment: You're right, .getFile() removes the "file:" at the begining of the string.

Comment: That's not what the problem is. When you run it after building the artifact, getResource() won't return a URI for a filename.